# How do I send a message to a window handle using AutoHotKey?

Tags: autohotkey, window-handles

I'm trying to detect if ffdshow is currently running on the computer using AutoHotKey.

Someone has suggested that I can achieve this by sending a message to the to the ffdshow window handle. If it succeeds, then ffdshow is running.

According to ffdshow, the window handle is `32786` and, according to the [AutoHotKey documentation](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/PostMessage.htm), I want to use `PostMessage` and then check `ErrorLevel`.

However at that point, I'm struggling to understand the documentation. I've got the following:

```
ControlHwnd := 32786
VarContainingID := 32786
PostMessage, 0x00, , , ,ahk_id %ControlHwnd%, ahk_id %VarContainingID%
MsgBox %ErrorLevel%
```

but that always reports a `1` indicating that it was unable to connect to the window handle - even though ffdshow is running.

I've also tried changing `PostMessage` to the blocking `SendMessage` but that always reports `FAIL`.

I'm clearly doing something wrong, but I'm not really sure what. Can anyone help?

Comment: I find it weird that window handles can have constant values, rather than always being dynamically assigned by the OS every time a new window spawns. However, according to [this doc](http://ffdshow-tryout.sourceforge.net/wiki/devel:controlling#configure_ffdshow_to_accept_remote_control), it's possible. The doc also says you have to make some configurations in order to make ffdshow accessible from an application; especially assigning the window handle value. Did you do that?

Comment: Also, why are you passing `ahk_id %VarContainingID%` as the window text? Have a close look at the parameter list!

Comment: 32786 seems more like a ahk_class, most hwnd look more like a hex number like 0x12345, You can use Winexist with detect hidden windows on to know if a window is running and it will also return the window handle, if you use the function version.

Comment: @MCL Yes, I've got "Remote control API" enabled and the user defined value has been left at the recommended `32786`.

Comment: Consider blackholyman's suggestion and try to work with `ahk_class 32786` and `DetectHiddenWindows, On`. Also, if you just want to check if ffdshow is running, isn't there a process you can look for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to blackholyman and MCL, I found the problem.

After digging around in the sample code found [here](http://ffdshow-tryout.sourceforge.net/wiki/devel:controlling#configure_ffdshow_to_accept_remote_control), it turns out there is a window class for ffdshow called `ffdshow_remote_class`.

As a result, the following code:

```
DetectHiddenWindows, On
WinGet, activeid, ID, ahk_class ffdshow_remote_class
MsgBox activeid = %activeid%
```

will return a hWnd value for ffdshow (stored in `activeid`) if it is running or nothing if it is not.